# Web Service 401: Unauthorized Error

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx, credentials

I am running a web service locally that connects to an outside server that i do not have access to.

I keep receiving the "401: Unauthorized" error even though the test credentials are confirmed exactly correct by the admins of this web service.

Do i need to adjust any IIS settings?

Here is a screenshot of the error.

[image]

```
        // Webservice
        IdentityService ws = new IdentityService();

        // Test Static Credentials
        string username = "twfnf";
        string password = "testme99";
        string domain = "testapps1";

        NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password, domain);

        CredentialCache credCache = new CredentialCache();
        credCache.Add(new Uri(ws.Url), "Basic", credentials);

        ws.Credentials = credCache;
        ws.PreAuthenticate = true;
        ws.AuthenticateUser();
```

Comment: Is `IdentityService` a SOAP style web service (like WCF web services, by default) or the older .NET 2.0 ASMX web service?

Comment: Could it be that "Basic" is not the auth system used? Basic doesn't use the domain property. If you try to connect to the URI in a browser with the user/pass given, does it 401 then too?

Comment: Are you using the Visual Studio generated proxy class for the service? I'm typically used to fiddling with the [`ClientCredentials`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms553830.aspx) property on a ClientBase-derived proxy class. Maybe we need to see some code from `IdentityService`.

Comment: @JonHanna - Yes, if i go to the URL and plug in those exact Login/Pass, i get authenticated.

Comment: Try it again with fiddler running. There would have been a 401 when you got asked for the user/pass, and then the 200 when you got let in. Looking at the headers should make it clear what auth scheme was in use (I'm betting either Digest or NTLM).

Comment: thanks guys, removing the Basic Authentication did it. although i'm stuck with the new error, but i'll try figuring it out. @SeanHanley - if you can make that the answer, i will mark it as correct. Thanks

Comment: new error, which i will troubleshoot: NACK: Error occured while processing request in FNF.Titlewave.IntegrationServices.Services.Identity.IdentityService.AuthenticateUser().
Exception --> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  at FNF.Titlewave.IntegrationServices.Core.Controllers.Identity.AuthenticateUserController.AuthenticateUserHelp(AuthenticateUserRequest request)
  at FNF.Titlewave.IntegrationServices.Services.Identity.IdentityService.AuthenticateUser(AuthenticateUserRequest request)

Comment: I'm not sure what I said that solved it for you...? Tell ya what, why don't you answer your own question with what you did. :) Especially because your new error looks like something specific to whatever FNF.Titlewave is and thus likely unrelated...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Removing the following code with Basic Authentication, fixed the issue.

```
CredentialCache credCache = new CredentialCache();
credCache.Add(new Uri(ws.Url), "Basic", credentials);
```

Final Code Working:

```
    // Webservice
    IdentityService ws = new IdentityService();

    // Test Static Credentials
    string username = "twfnf";
    string password = "testme99";
    string domain = "testapps1";

    NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password, domain);

    ws.Credentials = credentials;
    ws.PreAuthenticate = true;
    ws.AuthenticateUser();
```